# MSDN site does not work (ssl_error_protocol_version_alert)

Tags: firefox, ssl, msdn

For last few days MSDN site does not work for me in Firefox. I only got information

```
"ssl_error_protocol_version_alert"
```

What is going on? Is it something with my PC? This site works fine in Chrome, but it gives me information that it use TLS v1.0.

In Firefox, if i change security.tls.version.max from 3 to 1 - site is working, but probably i don't want to change this value.

Comment: The site can do only SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0. It works for me with the latest  Firefox 37.0.1  (and TLS 1.0) so maybe you have configured some other TLS related options?

Comment: I don't think that i used some of this options, but i have found button to refresh firefox (delete addons and reset modifications). I used it and it looks fine. Thanks for pointing 'maybe you have configured some other TLS related options?'